# How do I create a dictionary of methods in Python

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-machine, interpreter

I am trying to create a basic Intepreter/Virtual Machine class in Python 3.3.3 as follows:

```
class VirtualMachine:

    TERM_DICT = {
        0x01 : self.writeline,
        0x02 : self.expression
    }

    def test(self):
        opcode = 0x01 #hardcoded for testing purposes
        if opcode in self.TERM_DICT:
            term = self.TERM_DICT[opcode]
            term()
        else:
            print("opcode not recognised")

    def writeline(self):
        print("Writeline")

    def expression(self):
        return "Hello World"

myVM = VirtualMachine()
myVM.test()
```

When I try to run this script I get the error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "testVM.py", line 1, in <module>
>     class VirtualMachine:
>   File "testVM.py", line 4, in VirtualMachine
>     0x01 : self.writeline,
> NameError: name 'self' is not defined
> ```

Please tell me how can I get rid of this error and use the dictionary properly as a lookup to the correct class method.

Comment: Just move it to the end of the class (after you've *actually defined those methods*) and remove `self.` (which isn't in scope outside an instance method).

Comment: Your indenting is all messed up, I had a go at fixing it but got confused. Try indenting it properly so we can understand the code.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I've fixed the indenting, thanks. It's fine in the real code it was just messed up by pasting into SO.

Comment: Instead of mapping the functions (because then the descriptors can get annoying to work with) map the codes to the names of the methods, then just get the correct method with `getattr`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that's a valid solution in some situations - but don't forget that if your method/attribute names conflict or if you're using inheritance - someone, somewhere down the line is going to have a great deal of "fun" later :)

Comment: @JonClements I don't understand what you mean, `self.writelines` and `getattr(self, "writelines")` are by all means equivalent, having one mapping stored in the class definition with names and accessing the specific method as it is needed seems like the best solution to me.  if `writeline` is overridden in a subclass the same thing would happen in Edwin's solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't realise you could define data attributes **after** the methods or that the order of attributes within a class would make that much difference.

Comment: Methods are just callable attributes in Python, and the class definition is executed in order.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes sense - especially when I remember that Python is an interpreted language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but I guess this would give you a start:

```
class VirtualMachine:

    def __init__(self):
        self.TERM_DICT = {0x01 : self.writeline, 0x02 : self.expression}

    def test(self, opcode = 0x01):
        if opcode in self.TERM_DICT:
            term = self.TERM_DICT[opcode]
            term()
        else:
            print("opcode not recognised")

    def writeline(self):
        print("Writeline")

    def expression(self):
        return "Hello World"

myVM = VirtualMachine()
myVM.test()
```

for testing purposes, you probably want to change `return "Hello World"` into `print("Hello World")`

You could rewrite the `test()` function like this:

```
def test(self, opcode = 0x01):
    try:
        self.TERM_DICT[opcode]()
    except KeyError:
        print("opcode not recognised")
```

Based on comments you can keep the check of the opcode, something like this:

```
def test(self, opcode = 0x01):
    if opcode in self.TERM_DICT:
        self.TERM_DICT[opcode]()
    else:
        raise KeyError(opcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with storing a dictionary of methods is that, they need to be **bound methods**:

```
>>> myVM.writeline
<bound method VirtualMachine.writeline of <__main__.VirtualMachine object at 0x104e78c18>>
```

You cannot get a bound method without an instance to bind it to, so either you need to store the `TERM_DICT` for each instance created (as @Edwin van Mierlo has done) or look up the method name dynamically with `getattr`.

This requires very low change to your code, just store the method names as strings and then add one call to `getattr` in your test method:

```
class VirtualMachine:

    TERM_DICT = {
        0x01 : "writeline",  #use strings instead of bound methods!
        0x02 : "expression"
    }

    def test(self):
        opcode = 0x01 #hardcoded for testing purposes
        if opcode in self.TERM_DICT:
            method_name = self.TERM_DICT[opcode]
            term = getattr(self, method_name)    #use get_attr here!
            term()
        else:
            print("opcode not recognised")

    def writeline(self):
        print("Writeline")

    def expression(self):
        return "Hello World"

myVM = VirtualMachine()
myVM.test()
```

This was you are creating one bound method object for each time you run a `.test()` which is exactly what bound method objects were meant for.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to see how that works when I start adding other things like parameters.

Comment: pretty much the exact same as the answer you have accepted.  The only noticeable difference is that this way you can dynamically add to `VirtualMachine.TEST_DICT` to add to all instances where as your accepted answer would need to do it on a per-instance basis.  Other then that the two techniques should work identically.

Comment: Cool! `TEST_DICT` is immutable in my case anyway so that gives me two options.